# Understanding HiDPI displays and DPR

Tags: display, resolution

I'm trying to understand more about HiDPI displays and DPR

1. **What are the algorithms or processes behind making text sharper in HiDPI displays?**

   I'm guessing there is scaling involved since HiDPI displays render with more pixels i.e. 1440 x 900 resolution in HiDPI displays actually have 2880 x 1800 pixels.

   Obviously this isn't the only step, otherwise the text in the images shown would look the exact same since scaling doesn't actually change the "quality".

   What other techniques are used when rendering in HiDPI displays? Would anti-aliasing still be used?
2. **When resolution is set to 1440 x 900 in a HiDPI display. The Device Pixel Ratio (DPR) is set to 2.**

   But according to my understanding DPR is the ratio of physical pixels to logical pixels. In this case shouldn't DPR be 2560 / 1440 since my physical resolution is 2560 x 1600 and the logical resolution is 1440 x 900? I guess the DPR is 2 since 2880/1440 = 2 but 2880 isn't the linear physical resolution, it's suppose to be 2560. I'm confused

   1440 X 900 Standard Display
   [image: 1440 X 900 Standard Display]

   1440 x 900 HiDPI
   [image: 1440 x 900 HiDPI]

Comment: I recommend you forget about logical resolution and device pixel ratio if you want only a high-level understanding. They only needlessly complicate things. You don’t have “text at 1440×900” and “text at 2560x1440”. You have text and text with double the resolution. Just count the pixels and you’ll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ll attempt to answer your actual questions. But first, I urge you to let go of device pixel ratios and logical resolutions, they’re a can of worms.

On a normal flat panel display (CRTs are slightly different but also dead), you’ll have roughly 96 pixels per inch (PPI, often incorrectly called DPI). That’s the pixel density. It’s directly related to the physical display size and its native resolution. On a “High DPI” (really: “High PPI”) panel, the pixel density will be much higher, even up to three times. And that’s it, nothing more to it.

What to do with this high pixel density is of course also important. You wouldn’t want text a third of the size. So instead we render everything at three times the size. (If everything were easy, the device pixel ratio is just that: The scaling factor. But it’s exclusively a CSS thing. You should not bother with it as a user.) In essence, this is what makes everything look good. Suddenly we have a lot more pixels to make that “o” look ever so slightly more round, and the “g” isn’t just pixel goo.

The “algorithms and processes” are to just render the vector data that’s the font at a higher resolution. This isn’t bitmap scaling, it’s a higher-quality image made from scratch. For actual bitmaps (button images etc.), applications and websites often offer higher-resolution versions.

Nothing says you have to set the display scaling to 300% just because the pixel density is three times as high. You might also opt for a “zoomed out” display at 200%, to fit more content on the display. You can even use fractional scaling, but that’s not ideal.

---

So “not ideal” in fact, that some operating systems use “hacks” to support it. I guess you’re on macOS, which has this “looks like 1440×900” thing. You are right: The scaling slider is actually at the *2560 / 1440 = 1.77* option. However, that’s not a good factor for rendering purposes. So macOS actually lets everything run at 200% internally and then scales down the end result. This also affects performance. See also [this answer on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/421885).